# i want to a month and year to be displayed, along with the change in month and year on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want to a month and year to be displayed with arrow button on both right and left, on pressing left button it should display previous month and on pressing left button it should display next month

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add jquery library and jquery UI js and CSS

Here I have use UI datepicker and added following two options in datepicker function.

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
```

HTML

```
 <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
 <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

CSS

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
 }
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Chaims Dev.. but i need the changed month and year in a normal text box . how can i make it

Comment: Ok, you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/) for same like div next, prev functionality. @pawanr

Comment: Thank you very much @Chaims Dev